# How to Display a treeview Control in a webpart Or Alternatives

Tags: 2007, web-part, list, development, active-directory

Hi I developed a TreeView that listing groups and users in them, but for some reason I cant find the best way even googled it,

here's the Code

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        try
        {
            tree = new TreeView();


            foreach (SPUser User in SPContext.Current.Web.Users)
            {
                string GroupName = FormatUserLogin(User.Name);

                if (User.IsDomainGroup && GroupName != "" && DoesGroupExist(GroupName))
                {
                    TreeNode GroupNode = new TreeNode(GroupName);
                    List<ADUser> ADUsers = new List<ADUser>();

                    ADUsers = GetUsersFromGroup(GroupName);

                    foreach (ADUser member in ADUsers)
                    {
                        if (member != null && member.DisplayName != "")
                        {
                            TreeNode MemberName = new TreeNode(member.DisplayName);
                            GroupNode.ChildNodes.Add(MemberName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //loggingit
        }
    }
```

I tried adding control but still no gain

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Besides it's **not** recommended to start a local variable with an UpperCase.

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();

    try
    {
        tree = new TreeView();

        foreach (SPUser user in SPContext.Current.Web.Users)
        {
            string groupName = FormatUserLogin(user.Name);

            if (user.IsDomainGroup && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName) && DoesGroupExist(groupName))
            {
                TreeNode groupNode = new TreeNode(groupName);
                List<ADUser> adUsers = GetUsersFromGroup(groupName);

                foreach (ADUser member in adUsers)
                {
                    if (member != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.DisplayName))
                    {
                        TreeNode memberNode = new TreeNode(member.DisplayName);
                        groupNode.Nodes.Add(memberNode);
                    }
                }

                if(groupNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);
                }
            }
        }

        this.Controls.Add(tree);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //loggingit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right before your catch you need to add the TreeView control to the page.

```
        this.Controls.Add(tree);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //loggingit
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to your comment TimeToThine also needs to add TreeNodes to the tree object.

Comment: thanks guys, how I gonna do tht Farrel @adding TreeNodes to tree object